# Intersecting two polylines using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, intersection, topology

I have two polylines and would like to find the intersection(s) using ArcObjects / VB.NET.

I'm using the following code:

```
Dim topoOp As ITopologicalOperator = TryCast(pTestPoly2, ITopologicalOperator)
topoOp.Intersect(TryCast(pTestPoly1, IGeometry), ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.esriGeometryDimension.esriGeometry0Dimension)
Dim pOutPointCol As IPointCollection = TryCast(topoOp, IPointCollection)
```

In the resulting IPointCollection I get all the vertices of the input pTestPoly2, although there should be one intersection of the two polylines.

What's wrong with this approach?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the return value of the Intersect method instead of the TopologicalOperator. Try the following instead (I use C#, not VB.NET, so hopefully this works. The casting business is really confusing):

```
Dim topoOp As ITopologicalOperator = TryCast(pTestPoly2, ITopologicalOperator)
Dim pOutPointCol As IPointCollection = TryCast(topoOp.Intersect(TryCast(pTestPoly1, IGeometry), ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.esriGeometryDimension.esriGeometry0Dimension), IPointCollection)
```

Comment: +1 Also it is common practice to make sure both geometries have spatial reference and have been simplified (via ITopologicalOperator.Simplify).

Comment: Thanks, it works great! It is a bit confusing, though. Thanks Kirk for extra hints.